# GWT : Composite not displaying

Tags: java, gwt, layout, widget, composite

I have a this code for the layout :

```
grid = new Grid(15, 15);
        tiles = new Tile[15][15];

        for (int i = 0; i != 15; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j != 15; j++)
            {
                tiles[i][j] = new Tile('a');
                grid.setWidget(i, j, tiles[i][j]);
                tiles[i][j].setVisible(true);
            }
        }

        initWidget(grid);
```

I know it is working, because if I change the tile, by a Button, it works well.

Now my Tile class :

```
public class Tile extends Composite {

char character;

public Tile (Character c)
{
    this.character = c;
    buildWidget();
}

private void buildWidget()
{
    Label l = new Label(this.character+"");
    initWidget(l);
}
```

Why does all tiles are not displayed ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: By "all" you imply that *some* are being displayed? Have you checked the usual stuff - exceptions in DevMode console, browser, is the Grid and its contents really added to the DOM?

Comment: There is 0 Tiles displayed.
But for Buttons, they are 15x15

Comment: Which GWT version do you use?

Comment: Since you answered your own question please accept it so that it is shown as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't how I have solved this problem.
I have just shutdowned Eclipse and it worked again !

:(

Comment: If you were running in hosted mode the most recent version of Tile may not have been loaded.  If something isn't working after you make a change you should always try refreshing the hosted mode server and if that doesn't work, stop and restart it.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting the `initWidget(grid)` line just after `grid = new Grid(15, 15);`? (it's a long shot, but based on the code you showed, I can't see anything else wrong :/)